# strange padding problem around image

Tags: html, css, border, padding

I'm having a strange problem. I want to put border around the image, but it is showing some space at the bottom. Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4WKJY/
I don't want to put fixed height and width. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix it by making the img `display:block` in your CSS, [as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/4WKJY/2/).

Comment: could you precise what did you mean by 'removing space'? Simply arranging the code in a single line doesn't help

Comment: @denisk, the problem has nothing to do with whitespace, see my answer for why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to the other answer, it has nothing to do with whitespace in the markup, and removing the whitespace won't fix this.

The problem is that images are inline by default and the initial value for vertical alignment is `baseline`.  This means that the image is treated as if it were any other textual component of the page, and space is reserved beneath textual content for descenders - the tails on letters like lowercase 'j' etc.

To fix this, you either need to tell the rendering engine that the image shouldn't be treated like textual content - `.thumb img { display: block; }` will do this - or you can tell the rendering engine not to reserve space for descenders, and instead align the content to the very bottom - `.thumb img { vertical-align: bottom; }` will do this.

Edit: I seem to recall that old versions of Internet Explorer incorrectly handle whitespace, so removing the whitespace may have an effect there, but what I said above still stands; removing the whitespace is not a cross-browser fix for this problem.

Comment: Right you are; hopefully the OP will switch accepted to your answer. I've removed the misinformation from my answer.

Comment: This was driving me nuts all morning, thanks for the fix and great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, apply the css only to images:

```
.thumb img{
position: relative;
padding:2px;
float: left;
margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
border: solid 1px #ccc; 
}
```